# Как отсортировать массив кортежей по 3 значениям

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

Есть задача: нужно отсортировать массив кортежей - `[('name', 5, 5), (...), ...]`
Отсортировать так: вторые значения по убыванию, если они равны, то берем третье значение и сортируем по возрастанию, а если и они равны, то сортируем по алфавиту первого значения. Вот код:

```
n = int(input())

data = []
for i in range(n):
    a, b, c = input().split()
    data.append((a, int(b), int(c)))

for j in sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0], -x[2])):
    print(*j)
```

---

Почему-то не сортируется третье значение, хотя я его указываю. В итоге получается так:

```
# input
# 5
# alex 4 111
# gulette 6 920
# gret 2 87
# rubert 2 87
# tim 4 54

# мой вывод
# gulette
# tim
# alex
# gret
# rubert

# правильный вывод
# gulette
# alex
# tim
# gret
# rubert
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: А почему в правильном `alex` идет раньше `tim`? Вторые значения у них равны, а третье у `tim` меньше, чем у `alex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в кортеже для сортировки Вы берёте после второго элемента первый, хотя должны брать третий; кроме того, Вы ещё третий элемент сортируете по убыванию, хотя нужно по возрастанию.

Измените `(-x[1], x[0], -x[2])` на `(-x[1], x[2], x[0])`, и проблема будет решена.